# Why do we use radio waves for communication when gamma rays are more powerful?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, gamma-rays

NASA and other space programs primarily use radio waves to transfer information from spacecraft back to earth. Why don't they use gamma rays, which are more powerful?

Since radio waves have less energy than gamma rays, isn't it more likely for radio waves to get blocked by clouds, whereas gamma rays can pass through clouds?

Comment: Well, there's the whole business about gamma radiation being high enough energy to destroy your DNA and kill you...

Comment: Also, I can create radio waves with a few feet of wire and a penlight battery.

Answer (score 3):

Gamma rays are "more powerful" than radio waves only in the sense that the photon energy of the former is much higher; "gamma" radiation is usually taken to mean electromagnetic radiation arising from decays of atomic nucleusses and other nuclear processes; they have a wavelength of well less than a nanometer, whereas AM radio waves have wavelengths of hundreds of meters. A typical gamma photon energy is of the order of $1{\rm MeV}$; an optical photon is of the order of a few ${\rm eV}$ and a radio wave of the order of $10^{-8}{\rm eV}$.

Radio waves are easy to make at high powers - tens of kilowatts - with alternating electric currents produced by primitive electronic technology. They are also easy to modulate, *i.e.* to have a signal encoded onto them- with the same technology using sophisticated modulation schemes. The effects of such waves of even these powers on biological systems is very mild. Gamma rays of this power are hugely expensive to produced with human technology; only nuclear processes will make them. They can only be modulated by mechanical means - deflexion from mirrors and shutters, so would be useless for high speed communication - of the order of ${\rm GBps}$ which we nowadays routinely achieve with radio technology. Gamma rays of this power are utterly lethal to any biological system in their path. Moreover, their high photon energy means that they interact with and are swiftly (in comparison with radio broadcast distances) absorbed by air. They would be useless for terrestrial communications from this last point of view also. Radio waves, with their low photon energy, have very little interaction with clear air.

Comment: However, he's not asking about why they don't use gamma rays to communicate on _Earth_ , but rather, why they don't use them to communicate _in space_ . There's no humans living in space to any great extent and space is already extremely hostile to life by its very nature (hard vacuum, has its own radiation content anyways, hyper-kinetic missiles, etc.), so biological effects of gamma radiation on living organisms would be pretty irrelevant for such an application, I'd think. And furthermore, gamma rays in theory have vastly higher possible data rates than radio waves due to their profoundly

Comment: high frequencies (EHz and ZHz instead of MHz and GHz range), although there isn't, I believe, any application that we have now which would require such a tremendous data rate, much less hardware to modulate and demodulate that kind of signal. On the other hand, optical frequency (LASER) communications may be much more useful for similar reasons while being within the realm of existing technologies, and indeed, space agencies have been working on them iirc.

Comment: FWIW you can produce gamma ray, or at least X-ray, frequencies in a modulated form using what is known as a free-electron laser, however, I don't know if it can be modulated quickly enough to really take advantage of the bandwidth gains - and don't forget the "circuitry" controlling it would have to switch at that rate to get the data through which means it itself would effectively be processing gamma/X rays in its own right, which is impossible for ordinary electronics necessitating a radically different technology throughout the entire computer and data system that we don't have a clue as

Comment: to how to build yet much less even what form it might take (though perhaps sci-fi writers or other very speculative types have thought about this but I'm not aware of such work), if it's even physically possible at all. And _that_ , I'd think, would be the most important factor prohibiting its use. If one is thinking of using it at lower data rates where it has no advantage yet are still accessible to current or near-future technologies, optical frequencies would doubtlessly be the better "better than radio" option.

Answer (score 2):

First, available gamma rays sources are not "more powerful" compared to electromagnetic wave transmitters, i.e., they emit much less energy/time.
Second, gamma rays are extremely dangerous for the human and all other living beings. You would not survive next to such a source even when exposed only for a very short time.
Third, the signal modulation and detection of gamma rays is more cumbersome than that of radio waves.